# Fastest way to compare substring property between two strings in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Given two strings A and B, what is the fastest way to compare whether A is a substring of B or B is a substring of A?

```
 A LIKE '%' + B + '%' OR B LIKE '%' + A + '%'
```

or

```
CHARIDNEX(A,B) <> 0 OR CHARINDEX(B,A) <> 0
```

I believe its the former because it doesnt calculate the location.
  **Question 1:** is there a faster way to do it because I want to minimize the number of times B has to be used as B is a string I get by processing another column value.

As an additional note,

Basically I want to do something as follows with a column, C

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN A LIKE Processing(C) THEN 0
     WHEN A LIKE '%' + PROCESSING(C) + '%' OR PROCESSING(C) LIKE '%' + A + '%' THEN LEN(A) - LEN(PROCESSING(C))
END AS Score
FROM @table
```

where A and C are columns in table, @table. As can be seen, the number of times I am calling Processing(C) is huge as it is done for each record.
**Question 2:** Should I put Processing(C) it in a separate temp table and then run substring check against that column or continue with the same approach.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `charindex()` and `like` would have similar performance in this case.  Don't hesitate to test which is faster (and report back on the results so we can all learn).

However, this particular optimization probably won't make a difference to the overall query.  Your question may be an example of premature optimization.

Once upon a time, I thought that `like` performed worse than the comparable string operation.  However, `like` is optimized in many databases, including SQL Server.  As an example of the optimization, `like` is able to use indexes (when there is no wildcard or the wildcard is at the end).  `charindex()` does not use indexes.  If you are looking for matches at the beginning of the respective strings, then your query could possibly take advantage of indexes.

EDIT:

For your concern about `PROCESSING(c)`, you might consider a subquery:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN A LIKE Processing_C THEN 0
             WHEN A LIKE '%' + Processing_C + '%' OR Processing_C LIKE '%' + A + '%'
             THEN LEN(A) - LEN(Processing_C)
        END) AS Score
FROM (select t.*, PROCESSING(C) as Processing_C
      from @table
     ) t
```